Value Error: Data is ambiguous (for some reason, all x values are 1)
So I was coding an AI model that generates music based on text. I checked all the preprocessing functions, and they seem to work just fine. The x samples are the preprocessed text for training, and for some reason, they all end up as 1s when fed to the model.
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Embedding, Input, TimeDistributed, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import csv
import librosa
import os
import numpy as np

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

# Function to load audio
def load_audio(filepath):
    y, sr = librosa.load(filepath)
    return y, sr

# Function to extract audio features
def extract_features(audio, sr):
    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sr)
    return mfccs.T

# Function to encode text
def encode_text(text, tokenizer):
    sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])[0]
    return sequence

# Function to preprocess data
def preprocess_data(row, tokenizer, music_dir):
    song_path = os.path.join(music_dir, row['song'])
    print(f'Retrieved song path: {song_path}')
    audio, sr = load_audio(song_path)
    mfccs = extract_features(audio, sr)
    text = row['prompt']
    sequence = encode_text(text, tokenizer)
    padded_sequence = pad_sequences([sequence], maxlen=43, padding='post')
    expanded_padded_sequence = np.expand_dims(padded_sequence, axis=1)
    return mfccs, expanded_padded_sequence

# Load dataset and tokenize prompts
with open(file='dataset.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as dataset:
    reader = csv.DictReader(dataset)
    all_prompts = [row['prompt'] for row in reader]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(all_prompts)

# Prepare data for model training
preprocessed_audio = []
preprocessed_text = []
music_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'music')

with open(file='dataset.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as dataset:
    dataset.seek(0)
    reader = csv.DictReader(dataset)
    for row in reader:
        mfccs, expanded_padded_sequence = preprocess_data(row, tokenizer, music_dir)
        preprocessed_audio.append(mfccs)
        preprocessed_text.append(expanded_padded_sequence)

example_mfccs = preprocessed_audio[0]
mfccs_timesteps = len(example_mfccs)
mfccs_features = len(example_mfccs[0])
max_text_len = 43

audio_input = Input(shape=(mfccs_timesteps, mfccs_features), name='audio_input')
text_input = Input(shape=(max_text_len,), name='text_input')

num_lstm_units = 128

text_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=tokenizer.num_words, output_dim=64)(text_input)
text_encoder = LSTM(num_lstm_units, return_sequences=True)(text_embedding)
decoder = LSTM(num_lstm_units, return_sequences=True)(text_encoder)
decoder = LSTM(num_lstm_units)(decoder)
#decoder_upsampled = TimeDistributed(Dense(mfccs_features))(decoder)
model_output = Activation('sigmoid', name='model_output')(decoder)
model = Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=model_output)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
print(len(preprocessed_text))
print(len(preprocessed_audio))

# Train the model
epochs = int(input('Enter number of epochs: '))
model.fit(x=preprocessed_text, y=preprocessed_audio, epochs=epochs)
model.save('Ihy.tf', overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True)

And the error is:
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous. Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
'x' sizes: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
'y' sizes: 3982, 9838, 7699, 14171, 8417, 6547, 9082, 6763, 10255, 11647, 6754, 9491, 17134, 8414, 10078, 8303, 9107, 14320, 10145, 7339, 10338, 6933, 9302, 11573, 11859, 8915, 8949, 9709, 10538, 10924, 9507, 9987, 9445, 11571, 9563, 9705, 10081, 11245, 10239, 11909, 9678, 8788, 10041

I tried and tried to debug everything, and all the text preprocessing functions work just fine. They return good arrays. The audio is preprocessed correctly (y) and the text is just 1s (x).

The issue you're encountering stems from how you're preparing your data for training the model. Specifically, the problem lies in how you're handling the input (x) and output (y) data for your model,To resolve this, ensure the following:
Padding Sequences: Your text sequences (preprocessed_text) need to be padded to a fixed length (max_text_len). You're already doing this with pad_sequences, but let's ensure it's done correctly. padded_sequence = pad_sequences([sequence], maxlen=max_text_len, padding='post')[0]

Before feeding data into model.fit(), ensure that preprocessed_text and preprocessed_audio ,assert len(preprocessed_text) == len(preprocessed_audio), "Number of text and audio samples should match."
